# How to create a responsive full-row box-grid of 12 equal images with centered text?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am stuck for hours now and trying to solve the following problem and would appreciate your advice:

I am trying to create a fully responsive box-grid of equal images (400px x 400px each) with centered text on the basis of Bootstrap 3. The grid should use 100% of the screen-width and should contain 6 images per row on large screens, which perfectly align with each other without any white gaps or padding. On small screens the size should scale down responsively and every row should only contain 2 images.

```
 +--------------------------------------------------------+
 |                     Fixed Navbar                       |
 |--------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                        |
 |                        Header                          |
 |                                                        |
 +--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 +-------------------------------------------------------->
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 |        |         |        |         |        |         |
 +--------v---------v--------v---------v--------v---------+
 |                                                        |
 |                                                        |
 |                        Content                         |
 |                                                        |
 |                                                        |
 +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that the images are breaking out of the natural row width of 100%, creating an extra gap as you can see in the picture. So you have to scroll to the right to see the whole page, which is not intended.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image3.jpgg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div><img src="../img/image12.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nopadding {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be an ok solution for you to use pseudo-elements with attr(data) for the texts in the images? You'd just have to position them correctly with proper line-heights and you'd be set.

Comment: Whatever does the job and achieves the desired visual effect, but it has to be fully responsive to all screen sizes.

Comment: Well, pseudo-elements are not compatible with every browser, but they're a really quick and efficient way of generating content. Like this - http://codepen.io/rlacorne/pen/vCGhl . As for responsiveness, you can style them the same way you's style any other element with media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap automatically gives rows a margin-right and left property of -15px and then offsets that with padding on their columns. If you want to change the padding on the columns to zero, make sure you remove the margin that is inherently given to the rows as well.

Hopefully that helps!